# arraylist method to check if array list value is true

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to find the first true value in arraylist and then the next true I need to turn into false and I don't know how to do so. I tried to use isCorrect but it doesn't do what I want it to.
Here's what I wrote so far:

```
 private boolean singleOption;
    private ArrayList<Option> allOptions;

    public ClosedQuestion(int id, String title, boolean mandatory,boolean singleOption)
    {
        super(id,title,mandatory);
        this.singleOption=singleOption;
        allOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
    }

    public boolean isSingleOption() {
        return singleOption;
    }

    public void setSingleOption(boolean singleOption)
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < allOptions.size();i++)
        {
            if(allOptions.get(i).isCorrect()&&flag)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                for(int j=1; j< allOptions.size();j++)
                {
                    allOptions.get(j).setCorrect(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ClosedQuestion(ClosedQuestion other)
    {
        super(other);
        this.singleOption=other.singleOption;
        allOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
        for (Option o: other.allOptions)
        {
            allOptions.add(new Option(o));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `allOptions`? `Boolean` does not have `isCorrect` method.

Comment: Where is `allOptions` declared? _How_ is it declared? ... an arraylist of _what_? It must be some class because `.isCorrect()` and `.setCorrect()` aren't any standard sort of thing.

Comment: edited and modified

Comment: First of all, we still do not know what `Option` is. Second of all, `setSingleOption` could be easily implemented using `.iterator()` rather than an enhanced `for()` loop or two.